# Call custom method on component when props update

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a `YouTubeiFrame` react component that renders an empty div and then drops the YouTube iframe player in to that div using `componentDidMount`. All works fine. I have a `cueVideo` method defined on the component which uses the players
API to cue new videos:

```
cueVideo(videoId) {
  this.player.cueVideoById(videoId)
}
```

In different places in my app you can click a button or some another action to indicate that you  want to play a new video. When you perform this action the 'currentVideo' state is updated via redux and as a result the YouTubeiFrame component receives the new video id as an updated prop.

My question is how to call the `cueVideo` method above in reaction to the updated prop. I've considered using `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare `this.props.currentVideo` with the next props 
but concious this method is really supposed to return true/false so the render function can be called. All I want to do is call `cueVideo` when the currentVideo prop changes - I don't really need to re-render.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is `this.player` *inside* the component?

Comment: Yes, this.player is part of the component.

Comment: Why not call this at the top of the `render` method? `this.player.cueVideoById(this.props.videoId)`.  The `render` will be called regardless (because there was a state change).  And the virtual DOM won't make any DOM updates unless necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All I want to do is call cueVideo when the currentVideo prop changes - I don't really need to re-render.

When new props are received, React will automatically call `render()` to update your component. Once all the updates have been flushed to the DOM, React will also call `componentDidUpdate()` on your component to give you an opportunity to respond to the changes. As [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) says:

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated.

I would suggest this is the perfect place to call your code as needed.